# Accessing child entities in entity framework as AsQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i am using Entity Framework 4.0

i have two tables User & Messages

when i access messages for particular users as

```
currentUser.Messages.Where(m=> m.Subject=="hi");
```

when i see the query generated by above statement it looks like the query does not include the where condition. I assume that is is because Where is on IEnumerable here.

i changed my statement to

```
currentUser.Messages.AsQueryable().Where(m=> m.Subject=="hi");
```

but still it loads all messages for that user and executes where on code side instead of SQL. is there any workaround to this ?

Comment: If `Messages` is indeed `IEnumerable` it wouldn't issue a query to the database at all as it simply performs a Linq-to-Objects query.

Comment: messages are not loaded yet. Messages is of type EntityCollection